# Python code working for one file but not for an identically formatted longer file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I'm currently trying to get a function to work that reads a csv file and returns it's information as a list of dictionaries. The file it is reading is formatted like this:

```
3070,01:44:03,Aaron,Glue,Finished
480,02:06:47,Aaron,Collins,Finished
2228,01:42:06,Abigail,Swales,Finished
1519,01:24:11,Adam,Mcarthur,Finished
```

... and so on.

My code works fine, here it is:

```py
def readFile(filename):
    file = open(filename,'r')
    data = file.read()
    a = data.split()
    dataLists = []
    for term in a:
        termList = term.split(',')
        dataLists.append(termList)

    results = []
    for list in dataLists:
        competitorInfo = {'id': list[0], 'time': list[1], 'firstname': list[2], 'lastname': list[3]}
        results.append(competitorInfo)
    return results
```

Now I have two csv files, one called 'marathon.csv' and one called 'marathon10.csv'. marathon10.csv is the exact same as marathon.csv, but contains only 10 lines of information (easier for testing). In comparison, marathon.csv contains 2738 lines of information.

Whilst the program is returning the expected output when run on 'marathon10.csv', when run on 'marathon.csv' I receive this error:

[link to error on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuThk.png)

or shortened it says > 'IndexError: list index out of range' when reading the line beginning 'competitorInfo'.

I'll be honest I'm not sure where to go with this. I've emailed a few people who have told me it's probably to do with the sheer size of marathon.csv, but is that really it? I need this to work, and would like a proper explanation as to why I'm specifically getting a list index error if that is possible.

I understand some people might want to actually see marathon.csv, but I'm not sure how to share that. I assure you it is the exact same as marathon10.csv, with 2738 lines instead, each line is formatted the same way with 4 commas so I don't understand how I'm getting the error I'm receiving.

Thanks so much to anyone that can help :)

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name, it is a python keyword

Comment: don't link to imgur, copy paste the error into the question with proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

> I assure you it is the exact same as marathon10.csv, with 2738 lines instead

No, I assure you that it is not. There is most likely a missing comma in one of the lines. 2738 lines is not much.

You can try something like this instead and then check your output for `None`:

```py
def splitn(s, n):
    return (s.split(',') + [None] * n)[:n]

def readFile(filename):
    file = open(filename,'r')
    data = file.read()
    a = data.split()
    dataLists = []
    for term in a:
        termList = splitn(term, 5)
        dataLists.append(termList)

    results = []
    for dataList in dataLists:
        competitorInfo = {'id': dataList[0], 'time': dataList[1], 'firstname': dataList[2], 'lastname': dataList[3]}
        results.append(competitorInfo)
    return results
```

now, if there are less than `5` items in `term`, you will get the list padded with `None`

Comment: alternatively, you can use a `try/except` block and print out the `list` item which is throwing the exception if you want to fix the error in the source file.

Comment: thanks the try/except block found the problem. I was assured when sent both these files they were both formatted correctly, taught me to check that myself in future !

Comment: @raffoth the first step in programming is learning to not trust user provided data.